# Migration breaks for sqlite3 but run in mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

In two different migration I am adding index to two different table with same name. This migration works fine for mysql but break in slqite saying index name already exists. On removing the index name from any of the migrations it works fine for both. Can someone please take a look and see what is wrong in migration. Am I missing something?

```
 def up
    add_index :categories,          :category_mask, :name=> 'categories_pk'
  end
def up
  add_index     :category_mapping_by_ids, [:data_src_id, :category_id], :name=> 'categories_pk'
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using same index name (which shouldn't have worked in any DBMS, unsure why it's working in MySQL), i.e. `categories_pk`.

Try:

```
def up
  add_index :categories, :category_mask, :name=> 'categories_pk'
end
def up
  add_index :category_mapping_by_ids, [:data_src_id, :category_id], :name=> 'categories_mapping_pk'
end
```

Comment: definitely it is working when I change index name. Not sure why it is not breaking for MySQL.